# Regex (PHP) insert a space after letter combination Using Search Regex Wordpress Plugin

Tags: php, regex, wordpress

Firstly, I hate to be a pain but I'd like to know how to specifically do this in the Search Regex WordPress plugin. It's a popular plugin, but I don't understand how the Replace pattern works for it, it suggests that it accepts regex, but ends up just using literals.

How can I use a replace pattern to insert a space after a certain set of letters. I have the search pattern sorted, just need to know how to replace with a space.

So if we supposed I had a search that looked for every instance where 'testing' was followed by a few letters and I wanted to put a space after each instance.

e.g.

```
testingstring
```

should be replaced with...

```
testing string
```

Comment: Sorry to be a pain guys, I'd really like to know how this would work with the popular Search Regex plugin in WordPress. If I could get it working in that I'd be happy, it's too much hassle to dig into the WordPress backend all the time and do things manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I know my initial question is probably not very clear, but just in case this helps anyone in future, what I eventually realised is that I needed to split up my Regex search term using brackets e.g.

If I wanted to split up some words, where 'testing' was followed by a bunch of other letters than I would search for...

`/([tT]esting)([a-zA-Z]+)/`

Then the replace pattern would be...

`\1 \2`

the \1 would match the search pattern in the first set of brackets, then I have a space, and the \2 would match the search pattern in the second set of brackets. So let's take the following string...

`foo testingbar 123`

Under the search and replace patterns above, the string would be replaced by...

`foo testing bar 123`

Answer (score 1):

preg_replace('/(testing)([a-zA-Z])/', '$1 $2', $string);

Answer (score 1):

You should use `\b` at the start and a negative lookahead for your match:

```
preg_replace('#(\btesting)(?!\s)#', '$1 ', $origString);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_replace('/('.preg_quote($sSearch, '/').')(?! )/', '$1 ', $sSubject);
```